# How do I set a folder as a global include in Xcode, similar to Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2012, boost, objective-c++

In Visual Studio `/VC/include` I can put folders such as boost in order to be able to `include` them easily in Visual Studio projects.

Is there a similar place I can put folders for Xcode to be able to include them easily? Say, a place to drop boost into so I can use `include <boost/...>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag your folder in "supporting files" folder using xcode and then you can able to use them.